# C++ Passing an array of objects followed by an integer

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm hoping this will turn out to be a simple question. I'm looking at some C++ code where it's passing an array of structs to a method, example:

```
dosomething(arrayOfStructs + n);
```

The array was initialized at 256 items, and prior to calling the example method, it performs some work which populates the array with some items. The variable `n`, in this context, represents the number of items currently in the array.

I have no idea what the `n` variable does for the method being called, or even possibly to the array itself. The only thing I can think of is the number following the array is resetting the array size somehow. I could be totally off on that one.

I'm trying to follow the C++ code and try something similar in JavaScript. I am stuck on this `n` variable following the array.

Comment: `arrayOfStructs` decays to a pointer to the 1st element.  Adding `n` to this pointer will  point to the `n`th element.

Comment: It moves the pointer to the end of the array, basically to the nonexisting element `arrayOfStructs[n]` (since you said `n` is the number of items in the array). Or maybe you meant the number of items _already filled in_, in this case it's just pointing to the first element not yet filled in (again, `arrayOfStructs[n]`). We would need a bit more context of both the calling code and the `dosomething` function to understand what a suitable representation in JavaScript would be, because those concepts cannot be translated 1:1 as JS doesn't have pointers. But you can imagine `arr + x` as `&arr[x]`.

Comment: This is called pointer arithmetic. Please lookup the subject. Better yet, find [a good textbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and familiarize yourself with the fundamentals of the language.

Comment: CherryDT, thanks for the input. You pretty much got what I was trying to do. 'n' is the number of items currently filled in, and not the overall size per se. I got it. And R Sahu, thanks for the input as well. I definitely will look at the pointer arithmetic. My goal is not to leanr C++ per se but some things I do need to understand to translate some of it to JavaScript. I figured out a lot of thins already over to JS so thanks for the input everyone.

Comment: There's no Javascript equivalent to pointer arithmetic, you're going to have to understand and then rewrite the code. Presumably you could pass `arrayOfStructs` and `n` as separate variables to the function.

Comment: Understood john. I have an  idea now of what I need to do. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that `n` has an integer type.

In the expression used as an argument of this call

```
dosomething(arrayOfStructs + n);
```

the array designator `arrayOfStructs` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. Adding the integer value `n` the pointer to the first element of the array is moved to the n + 1 element of the array (if to count elements starting from 1). This is called the pointer arithmetic.

You can consider this call like

```
dosomething( &arrayOfStructs[n]);
```

To make it more clear consider this simple demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

void display( const int *p )
{
    std::cout << *p << ' ';
}

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        display( a + i );
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        display( &a[i] );
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 2 3 
1 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad for the info